# Logback root output configuration

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I would like to see all info level output from console, and ONLY warn output from file.

Info level output on console is clearly shown, but all Info output is saved on file too, not only warn level output.

Here is my logback configuration. Any wrong in here?

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder"> 
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{20} [%mdc{threadid}] - [%mdc{useroid} : %mdc{sessionid}]%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="consoleFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/console.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level | %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: You can't have two root level tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose I suggest to use filters in your appender. More specifically, if you want to see only INFO on console you can add a specific LevelFilter in your console appender, if you want to see all logs equals or above to INFO, you can use ThresholdFilter.

Here there is a possible solution for your task:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch> 
        </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder"> 
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{20} [%mdc{threadid}] - [%mdc{useroid} : %mdc{sessionid}]%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                    <level>WARN</level>
                    <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                    <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/console.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level | %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
```